# C++ (STL map) equivalent method to Python's setdefault

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, stl, setdefault

So most likely this question had been asked already. Couldn't find it.

Every time I define a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and want to insert some value to it, I use this piece of code:

```
using IntVector = vector < int > ;
map<int, IntVector> mapTmp;

int iKey = 7;
int iVal = 9;
if (mapTmp.find(iKey) == mapTmp.end())
    mapTmp.insert(pair<int, IntVector>(iKey, IntVector()));
mapTmp[iKey].push_back(iKey);
```

What annoys me is the 3 lines:

```
if (mapTmp.find(iKey) == mapTmp.end())
    mapTmp.insert(pair<int, IntVector>(iKey, IntVector()));
mapTmp[iKey].push_back(iVal);
```

Python offer a very useful dict function called: [setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm), that essentially combine those 3 lines into one beautiful line. Say I want to write it in C++, it would be:

```
mapTmp.setdefault(iKey, IntVector()).push_back(iVal);
```

#### Questions

1. Does `C++` offer such functionality?
2. If not, does everyone write those 3 lines all the time?

Comment: As for the first two lines, `!mapTmp.count(iKey)` is a suitable replacement for `mapTmp.find(iKey) == mapTmp.end()` and `{iKey, {}}` is a suitable replacement for `pair<int, IntVector>(iKey, IntVector())` in that context.

Comment: There's also `make_pair(iKey, IntVector())` if you want it to be absolutely clear that it's a pair and not some other two-member aggregate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map defined by the C++ standard library has the somewhat counter-intuitive behaviour that merely calling `operator[]` can *mutate* the array. In other words, your "if not in map then insert a default" logic is entirely superfluous - the following two segments are equivalent:

```
if (mapTmp.find(iKey) == mapTmp.end())
    mapTmp.insert(pair<int, IntVector>(iKey, IntVector()));
mapTmp[iKey].push_back(iVal);
```

and:

```
mapTmp[iKey].push_back(iVal);
```

In the second case, if `iKey` does not exist in the map, it is first default-initialized. For a vector, that's the same as inserting an empty vector.

For the general case that Python's `setdefault` covers, I don't know of anything. You might be able to get the effect by providing a custom allocator for the map, but I don't think I'd recommend it.